# Union with a timediff statement in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select, union

Not sure I'm going about this correctly to begin with - I have two valid SQL select statements that I would like to run together.

The first is
       `SELECT * FROM mytable;`

The second is
       `Select TIMEDIFF(time2,time1) as diff from mytable;`

So I thought maybe
       `SELECT * FROM mytable UNION Select TIMEDIFF(time2,time1) as diff from mytable;`

But of course, the second statement doesn't have the same number of columns because it isn't a separate table. Those of you awesome at this will be able to figure it out in no time, I am sure.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: _use row_number() then join_

Comment: The goal is to be able, in php, to have one $result=mysql_query() to populate a table using echo($row["columnnames"]) and include the "new" diff column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select TIMEDIFF(time2,time1) as diff, t.* from mytable t;
```

Is it what you want?

Comment: Thank you, that' works perfectly. I'm not 100% sure why, though. Aliasing?